# Can't require user to select a variant in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm using the paid theme *Prestige* - and I have been trying to make it so that users must select a variant before proceeding to check out.

For ex: On the product page, we can create a size variant called "Select Your Size", but users can add the product to cart with "Select Your Size" selected, instead of small, medium, large, etc..

I know it's probably just a few lines of JavaScript that needs to be added, but since I did not create the code for this theme, it's hard for me to figure out where to place it/what to replace.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: The easiest solution would be all HTML. Change the first `<Option>` to be an empty string and place the "Select Your Size" string outside as a label. Then add the `required` attribute to the `<Select>` element. The browser will enforce the selection for you. The downside is that the esthetics of the prompt may not meet your needs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.